# How to get request and response as string after RequestDispatcher forward

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, netflix-zuul

In my Springboot application, I use `RequestDispatcher` forward to send the request and response to a remote service. Now I need to get that `response` and `request` as string to log it into database.
The `request` and `response` both contain JSON data.

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(configAPI.getUserByPhoneUrl());
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

The `RequestDispatcher` will modify the response in-place. So after the `forward()` function, I'm unable to get the json from the response created by `requestDispatcher.forward(request, response)`.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserByPhone", method = {RequestMethod.GET}, produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
    public void getUserbyIsdn(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            // Forward the request to the remote service
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(configAPI.getUserByPhoneUrl());
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
            // response now has result from remote service
            // TODO: print out json in response here
    }
```

Any idea on how to get response as json?

I've try using `HttpServletResponseWrapper` to access the response but unable to.
Example code using `HttpServletResponseWrapper`:

```java
HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request);
            HttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response);

            // Forward the request to the remote service
            request.getRequestDispatcher(configAPI.getUserByPhoneUrl()).forward(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
```

but is result in NullPointerException because `ApplicationContext` request is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trying out, I was able to get response and request json string using `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` and `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`. The controller now become like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserByPhone", method = {RequestMethod.GET}, produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
    public void getUserbyIsdn(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        requestWrapper.getRequestDispatcher(configAPI.getApi_getUserbyIsdn_user()).forward(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
        // do what ever you want here with response and request
        apiLogService.addApiLog(requestWrapper, responseWrapper, "getUserByIsdn", timer);

        // have to has this to return original response of other service
        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
```

Function `addApiLog`:

```java
public void addApiLog(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request, ContentCachingResponseWrapper response) {
    String requestJson = IOUtils.toString(request.getContentAsByteArray());
    String responseJson = IOUtils.toString(response.getContentAsByteArray());
    // handle json String using JSONObject or GSON as needed
}
```